# Executing command externally to already opened PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell, batch-file, scripting, automation

Is there any way I can execute a command on an already opened PowerShell externally, may be by running a separate batch file or from a python script? For example I am working on a PowerShell right now and I want to perform a 'cd' command but by running a python script; and the directory inside the opened PowerShell will automatically change without opening a new PowerShell window.

Comment: I sense an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, hi. I am not sure how to be more specific about what I want. I already mentioned an example to be more specific. If I can at least achieve that, I will know there is a way.

Comment: In the already open PowerShell window type, `Set-Location -Path C:\YourPath`. If that's not what you wanted, then your question is not clear or specific enough.

Comment: @Compo I think he is asking how can he effect a powershell shell from another application like CMD or Python. Like he wanted to change directories ....how could he enter CD in python or CMD and have powershell change also....???? Ether way....Why????? why would you ever need this?

Comment: Thinking means the question is not clear or specific enough. And if that is the intention then they'd likely be looking for a solution using simulated key presses etc.

Comment: @Nafis *What* you want is pretty clear. My question was *why* you think you need this. Because I fail to see a situation where non-interactive automation of an interactive console would make sense.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I want to be able to automatically change a directory and launch a program, but I also want to see the verbose, console logs, error messages etc. Then when I don't want this program, I want to close and launch another program same way (by running some scripts), in the same terminal/PowerShell, and monitor it. Also I want to be able to input commands in the opened shell manually when I need to. Long story short, there will be one terminal, so I can monitor what's going on, but I can also work on it manually when I want to, after closing other running tasks of course.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to look into [background jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288.aspx).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I don't want anything to run in background and there will be only one task running at the same time, and that will be visible on the opened terminal. There will be only one terminal window. So far I think it's not possible in PowerShell. I will have to try making a shell window myself to perform this.